# Can I prevent Maven from compiling everything?

Tags: maven

I built a tiny test project, with two Java sources in one package. If I run Maven twice in succession, with no edits, Maven evidently checks the timestamps, and determines that everything is up to date, and compiles nothing. However, if I touch either source file, Maven seems to recompile all sources. I should note that I'm using "mvn compile" not "mvn install".

Now, I know that there are situations (notably switching on enum types or Strings) where a change in one source file mandates a recompilation of all the ones that use it, but this all-or-nothing approach to compilation seems aggressive, contrary to the behavior of older tools (notably make and its variants) and likely to contribute to some of the insanely long build times that projects often seem to suffer from.

So, question: Is there a way to tell Maven to compile only those sources that are newer than their paired binaries, and if so how is that done?

(As a side question, are there other situations that would require the recompile-everything approach, other than the one I mentioned? I note that it's likely those particular problems will go away in a future release of Java, so it would be nice if the tool were ready to benefit too).

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: Because some projects have enough source files to take an hour, or more, to build--and unsurprisingly, that makes a TDD approach pretty hard to achieve :)  Actually, any approach!

Yes, you can argue that such projects are badly organized, but that's beside the point; the real world is full of compromises, and sometimes the more pressing problem is to get something else fixed first, or one might simply not have the authority to instigate the wholesale changes needed :)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not use clean and nothing has changed maven will not needlessly recompile, sor for example

```
mvn clean install
```

Will delete all the target folders, then build everything, because there are no targets.

```
mvn install
```

Will only build modules where code has changed after the last target build for that module. It's intelligent enough to know if a module has a changed dependency necessitating a rebuild.

That said, just do a mvn clean everytime, it's only a bit of CPU, if you want to skip tests to speed things up.

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

Comment: But the entire project gets built, not just the file that changed, right?

Comment: And, to reiterate, it's not the CPU, it's the time it takes.